# UsePathBase and Swashbuckle for Swagger Documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have setup my ASP.NET core using the middleware `UsePathBase("/api/something/else")`, and my controllers are defined like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

and the specific endpoint is defined like this

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<ForecastRecord>> Get()
```

When I run the application I can access the endpoint like this:

```
/WeatherForecast
/api/something/else/WeatherForecast
```

When I get the Swagger documentation I get this:

```
"servers": [
    {
      "url": "/api/something/else"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/WeatherForecast": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "WeatherForecast"
        ],
```

As you can see the `servers` element have a entry to `/api/something/else` but when I run the SwaggerUI I don't see the endpoints prefixed with `/api/something/else`:

[image: Swagger Documentation]

I am wondering if there is a way to force the SwaggerUI to prefix the endpoints with the value set with `UsePathBase`

Comment: Have you tried using an operation filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing here and there with the order of middleware calls, I have found the right combination to solve the problem described in this question is:

```
//1. Add SwaggerUI
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.RoutePrefix = "api/something/else";
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Name");
});

//2. Set BasePath
app.UsePathBase("/api/something/else");

//3. Add Swagger
app.UseSwagger();
```

Following that order the Swagger UI will show properly the endpoints:
[image: SwaggerUI]

Comment: Not working in .NET 5.

Answer (score 1):

As an update to GustavoTM answer you need to do the below to get it working now.

```
    //1. Add SwaggerUI
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.RoutePrefix = "api/something/else/swagger";
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/something/else/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Cool API");
    });
    
    //2. Set BasePath
    app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api/something/else"));
    
    //3. Add Swagger
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
    });
    
    //4. use routing
    app.UseRouting();
```

Comment: This order seems to work for me in .Net 6.0.