# Can CreatedAtAction in .NET 6 Web API automatically include the base path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, http-headers

We have a .NET 6 Web API that we deploy with a base path = "api".

```cs
// Startup.cs
private string PathBase => Configuration.GetValue<string>("pathBase") ?? "/";

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UsePathBase(PathBase);
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}
```

```cs
// ItemController.cs

[HttpGet("v1/items/{itemId}")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var item = // Get an Item
    return Ok(item);
}

[HttpPost("v1/items")]
public IActionResult Post()
{
    var item = // Create an Item
    var routeValues = new { itemId = item.Id };
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(ItemController.Get), routeValues, item);
}
```

With the base path, when we inspect the response the location header doesn't include the "api".

```
// actual
location: https://localhost:5001/v1/items/1
```

Is there any suggestions we can do to make sure the location header includes the "api" base path so that it looks like:

```
// expected
location: https://localhost:5001/api/v1/items/1
```

Comment: **ASP.NET** or **ASP.NET Core** - or really both?

Comment: I believe so as "Core" was dropped after version 3 and we're now on .NET 7. But this problem I think still exists in v3.

Comment: Are you testing your requests in SwaggerUI? If so this could help maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460266/usepathbase-and-swashbuckle-for-swagger-documentation

Comment: For the complete platform - yes, there's .NET 5, .NET 6, .NET 7 - but it's still **ASP.NET Core** 5, 6, 7 (which is very much clearer, in my opinion) ....